# Populating uitableviewcell after filtering, cell content always the same

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I'm working on a simple problem which is populating UITableViewCells after searching and filtering.

Here is some code for populating the cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
   .... etc
        if ([self.searchController isActive] && (![self.searchController.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""])) {
            NSArray *results = [self.searchResults mutableCopy];
            if (results.count == 0) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                for (NSInteger i = 0; i < results.count; i ++) {
                    NSString *fullName = [results objectAtIndex:i];
                    ((SSContactTableViewCell *)cell).fullNameLabel.text = fullName;
                }
            }
        } else { .. etc
```

I separated a lot of my code so I could debug it, and here is my results when I search for the letter "t":

I can see that I do have 6 items in my results array, with all contains the letter 't'.
[image]

The rest looks good as well, firstName is "Clayton Farr" and cell content is "Clayton Farr"
[image]
[image]

However, on my app, only the name "Hally Wernstorm" fills. 
[image]

I don't want this to happen of course, so I was wondering where in the code am I getting all "Hally Wernstorm" back?

Some code that I've wrote:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (self.contactsButton.selected) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContactCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ([self.searchController isActive] && (![self.searchController.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""])) {
            NSArray *results = [self.searchResults mutableCopy];
            if (results.count == 0) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                for (NSInteger i = 0; i < results.count; i ++) {
                    NSString *fullName = [results objectAtIndex:i];
                    ((SSContactTableViewCell *)cell).fullNameLabel.text = fullName;
                }
            }
        } else {
            NSArray *sectionArray = [self.contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [self.indexTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]];
            NSString *fullName = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            ((SSContactTableViewCell *)cell).fullNameLabel.text = fullName;
            ((SSContactTableViewCell *)cell).specialtyLabel.text = [self.specialities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [((SSContactTableViewCell *)cell).avatarButton setTitle:[NSString initialsOfStrings:[fullName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]]];
        }
    }
    else if (self.patientsButton.selected) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PatientCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSArray *sectionArray = [self.patients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [self.indexTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]];
        ((SSPatientTableViewCell *)cell).fullNameLabel.text = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if (self.favouritesButton.selected) {
//        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContactCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UISearchControllerDelegate

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
    if (searchString == nil) {
        self.searchResults = [self.contacts mutableCopy];
    } else {
        self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSString *name in self.contacts) {
            if ([name.lowercaseString containsString:searchString.lowercaseString]) {
                [self.searchResults addObject:name];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope {
    [self updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self.searchController];
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (self.searchController.active) {
        if ( self.searchResults.count == 0 && (![self.searchController.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]) ) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 26;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.contactsButton.selected) {
        NSArray *sectionArray = [self.contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [self.indexTitles objectAtIndex:section]]];
        return [sectionArray count];
    } else if (self.patientsButton.selected) {
        NSArray *sectionArray = [self.patients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [self.indexTitles objectAtIndex:section]]];
        return [sectionArray count];
    } else if ([self.searchController isActive] && (![self.searchController.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""])) {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    return 6;
}
```

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: No matter which cell you're creating, you set fullName to the final thing in results.  (Actually, you set it to all the names, one after another, but you finish the loop with the last one.)

Comment: Oh thanks you are right! I've made this mistake before, but I forget all the time.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the appropriate way to manage tableView search.

You need to create a filtered array and to reload your tableView based on it each time it changes.

Comment: I don't normally do it with a for loop; this is what I did before:        
            ((SSContactTableViewCell *)cell).fullNameLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; but I have problem with sections I have to solve. Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

Using for loop is not an correct way.

As you are using for loop you are always getting the same name.

Kindly go through this and use this [search bar in objective-c demo](http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/)

Comment: Thank you. I normally do it another way, which is something like:  
((SSContactTableViewCell *)cell).fullNameLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; but I have problem with sections I have to solve, which is why I tried the for loop way.